# Does iOS 8 support IndexedDB with UIWebView?

Tags: uiwebview, ios8, indexeddb

I see that Safari on iOS 8 has support for `IndexedDB`, but I can't find anything about `UIWebView`. From my preliminary testing, it looks like it doesn't, but I'm hoping someone out there has a concrete answer for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From here: http://www.sencha.com/blog/apple-shows-love-for-html5-with-ios-8

◾IndexedDB is not available in iOS 8 “UIWebView” or Home screen apps

Answer (score 6):

`UIWebView` does not support `IndexedDB`, but `WKWebView` does.

Here is a post of technologies tested on the various web viewers available on iOS8:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cordova-dev/201409.mbox/%3CCAD66QQSYuEhWkW9-b_TN4MK-+MO5MfjU2cMjkhbRvaxCWF51eA@mail.gmail.com%3E

```
iPod Touch iOS 8 *Safari*
UserAgent - Mozilla/5.0 (iPod touch; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X)
AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A365
Safari/600.1.4
Sunspider - 1825ms Overall
HMTL5 Test - 440/555
- Seamless iFrame - No
- 2D Graphics Path Support - Yes
- Web GL 3D Graphics - Yes
- IndexedDB - Yes
- Objectstore ArrayBuffer Support - Yes

iPod Touch iOS 8 *HomeScreen*
UserAgent - Mozilla/5.0 (iPod touch; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X)
AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12A365
SunSpider - 1801.0ms Overall
HTML5 Test - 427/555
- Seamless iFrame - No
- 2D Graphics Path Support - Yes
- Web GL 3D Graphics - Yes
- IndexedDB - No
- Objectstore ArrayBuffer Support - No


iPod Touch iOS 8 *WKWebView*
UserAgent - Mozilla/5.0 (iPod touch; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X)
AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12A365
SunSpider - 1822.8ms Overall
HTML5 Test - 438/555
- Seamless iFrame - No
- 2D Graphics Path Support - Yes
- Web GL 3D Graphics - Yes
- IndexedDB - Yes
- Objectstore ArrayBuffer Support - No


iPod Touch iOS 8 *UIWebView*
UserAgent - Mozilla/5.0 (iPod touch; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X)
AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12A365
SunSpider - 7114.6ms Overall
HTML5 Test - 427/555
- Seamless iFrame - No
- 2D Graphics Path Support - Yes
- Web GL 3D Graphics - Yes
- IndexedDB - No
- Objectstore ArrayBuffer Support - No


*iOS 8 Notes*
- Seamless iFrame was removed compared to iOS 7.1.2
- IndexedDB is only supported in Safari & WKWebView App
- Objectstore ArrayBuffer is only supported in Safari & WKWebView App
- UIWebView is ~4x slower then WKWebView for JS (Sunspider results)
- WKWebView cannot load local files (issue for Cordova/Phonegap/Offline
Solutions)
- No UserAgent difference between UIWebView and WKWebView.
```